# How to use Aptana using Eclipse and then Jquery

Tags: javascript, eclipse, aptana

Hi I have Eclipse Indigo Java EE, I recently got to know that Aptana can be used for JavaScript development and also have Jquery with Eclipse. Can someone please help me how to use Aptana after we install Aptana in Eclipse (Help->Install New Software). I need steps to that i should follow for it to work please?

And also how to make Eclipse and Aptana use Jquery please.

Answer (score 3):

Aptana just adds new editors to Eclipse, which should get used by default based on the file-extension of the file you are opening.  If you want to explicitly control which editor gets used, right-click on the file and choose "Open With" (and then select which editor you want to use).

If you want to change which editor gets used by default for a given file-extension, go to the preferences for General => Editors => File Associations (and you also might want to look at General => Content Types also, as it relates).

Comment: P.S. Aptana can *wreck* your Eclipse install if you are unlucky (the Aptana people are just awesome at adding functionality and terrible at ensuring code quality).  If you start noticing issues with Eclipse after installing Aptana, you may want to uninstall Eclipse and just install the full Aptana editor (which is almost the same as Eclipse, but makes the Aptana stuff work better) or, if you need vanilla Eclipse (eg. for Java development), use both independently ...  but hopefully you'll luck out and Aptana won't cause you any issues :-)